# filter the exact word in datatables

Tags: php, search, datatables, drop-down-menu

I am using datatables plugin in my php script. For searching, I have a drop down box having two values "Active" and "Inactive". When I am searching by "Active" word, then it is showing the records, containing "Active" as well as "Inactive". I know this is happening only for that particular word("Active").

Then how to stop this wild cards search for this drop down box.

My code is like:

```
    $("#example").dataTable().columnFilter(
     {  

      "aoColumns": [                                    
        null,null,null,null,
{
         type: "select",
         values: [ 'Active', 'Inactive' ]
        },
      null                                                   ]
     });
```

Comment: can u display the query that get executed ??

Comment: Possible duplicate? Is your answer found here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047228/search-exact-word-by-datatables?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Datatables have default option of search being caseinsensitive, so try to put the following while initialising your datatable.

```
$("#example").dataTable(
 {  

  "bCaseInsensitive": false,
 });
```